# C# LINQ: does the linq query only return deferred enumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, .net-core

I have a method

> GetPostsByCategory

I can do it like the approach A to re-use what I have

**A**

```
public IEnumerable<Post> GetPostsByApartmentId(
    string apartmentId,
    int pageIndex,
    int pageSize,
    int max = 50)
{
    var itemsPerPage = Math.Max(pageSize, max);
    return _context.Post
        .Where(p => p.ApartmentId == apartmentId && !p.Disabled)
        .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * itemsPerPage)
        .Take(itemsPerPage);
}

public IEnumerable<Post> GetPostsByCategory(
    string categoryId,
    string apartmentId,
    int pageIndex,
    int pageSize,
    int max = 50)
{
    return GetPostsByApartmentId(apartmentId, pageIndex, pageSize, max)
        .Where(p => p.CategoryId == categoryId);
}
```

But, I am concerned about the performance for the A, 
so here is the approach **B**

```
public IEnumerable<Post> GetPostsByCategory(
    string categoryId,
    string apartmentId,
    int pageIndex,
    int pageSize,
    int max)
{
    var itemsPerPage = Math.Max(pageSize, max);
    return _context.Post
        .Where(p => p.ApartmentId == apartmentId && !p.Disabled && p.CategoryId == categoryId)
        .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * itemsPerPage)
        .Take(itemsPerPage);
}
```

However, I remember I read some articles saying: the Lambda Expression(or LINQ, can't remember) does not really execute the query, it just constructs the query and it only gets executed when it is needed or by calling something like ToList(). 
So if this is the case, then both A and B should be same.
Can some one please confirm this?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Why are you concerned about the performance? The performance of what exactly, an extra method call? Have you tried measuring the difference?

Comment: It would appear you're using Entity Framework, and returning an IEnumerable materializes the result up till then. Is your actual question _"How to extend a Where statement"_?

Comment: I think that if you change a return type of `GetPostsByApartmentId` to `IQueryable<Post>` there will be almost no difference between **A** and **B**

Comment: There is more important question you should ask first: Does approach A returns the same results with approach B? I have the suspicion that it doesn't. A slow code that produces correct results is always preferable to a fast code that produces wrong results.

Comment: hi @TheodorZoulias You are right. The approach A isn't correct. so I have to use B.

Comment: @AleksAndreev Yes! IQueryable! that's the thing I should use for deferred results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Option B would be fast, as it is getting filtered data in single go.

A will retrieve all data based on condition and then it will filter based on category. There is possibility that it may endup retrieve unintended data.

Edit:

It would be interesting in case of Stored procedure how it will behaves.

If you have access to profiler then it would be easy to check what is final SQL statement reches to sqlserver for execution.

I'm not very much sure about, internal mechanism of entity framework.

But from your code I think that to achieve same thing compiler/EF have to do something behind the scene twice.

Comment: I don't think that A retrieves any data by itself. It just returns a deferred enumerable. The data are retrieved when the enumerable is consumed.

Comment: thanks @TheodorZoulias that what I read previously, but I cannot find the reference, could you please help?

Comment: @Franva I don't know much about the Entity Framework, so I am not familiar with its documentation. I know well LINQ for Objects, that behaves this way.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias It's about what's executed in the database, and what's executed locally. Approach A will retrieve `itemsPerPage` items from the database, and then will filter them further in memory. Approach B does the filtering in the database (and before limiting it to `itemsPerPage` items).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thanks, I think it is the behaviour of LINQ for Objects. Does it have a name?

Comment: @Franva it is called [Deferred Execution](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-deferred-execution).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias appreciated :)